# Feching the values from xml on the condition check

Tags: php, xml

I got a problem

```
<?php

$movie_name = 'Dabangg';

$url = sprintf(
    'http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/mapi/%s',
    rawurlencode(trim($movie_name))
);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

if (!$xml) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf("Failed to open XML from URL '%s'.", $url));
}

$movies = $xml->movies->movie;

foreach ($movies as $movie) 
{
    $movie_id = $movie->id;

    if ($movie_id && is_int($movie_id)) 
    {
        break;
    }
}

echo $movie_id;
```

The above code I am using to fecth the movieid . Now I realized that when I search for a particular movie it fetches two movies result

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<opensearch:Query searchTerms="Dabangg"/>
<opensearch:totalResults>2</opensearch:totalResults>
<movies>
<movie>
<score/>
<popularity>3</popularity>
<translated>true</translated>
<adult>false</adult>
<language>en</language>
<original_name>Dabangg</original_name>
<name>Dabangg</name>
<alternative_name/>
<type>movie</type>
<id>44425</id>
<imdb_id>tt1620719</imdb_id>
<url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/44425</url>
<votes>6</votes>
<rating>5.6</rating>
<certification>PG-13</certification>
<overview>
Set in Uttar Pradesh, Dabangg is the story of a corrupt police officer played by Salman Khan and highlights the flaws and loopholes in the system. The film primarily deals with the unlawful practices in the states of UP and Bihar.
</overview>
<released>2010-09-10</released>
<images>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w92/lfI4ihj4qa8Obyst9miTSNzHCqF.jpg" size="thumb" width="92" height="138" id="4ea685f034f8633bdc00b45f"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w154/lfI4ihj4qa8Obyst9miTSNzHCqF.jpg" size="w154" width="154" height="231" id="4ea685f034f8633bdc00b45f"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/lfI4ihj4qa8Obyst9miTSNzHCqF.jpg" size="cover" width="185" height="278" id="4ea685f034f8633bdc00b45f"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/lfI4ihj4qa8Obyst9miTSNzHCqF.jpg" size="w342" width="342" height="513" id="4ea685f034f8633bdc00b45f"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w500/lfI4ihj4qa8Obyst9miTSNzHCqF.jpg" size="mid" width="500" height="750" id="4ea685f034f8633bdc00b45f"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/lfI4ihj4qa8Obyst9miTSNzHCqF.jpg" size="original" width="1000" height="1500" id="4ea685f034f8633bdc00b45f"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w300/sNoWUZD4S3C4gqWVwvifuiwsJ4m.jpg" size="thumb" width="300" height="169" id="4ea6860234f8633bdc00b477"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w780/sNoWUZD4S3C4gqWVwvifuiwsJ4m.jpg" size="poster" width="780" height="439" id="4ea6860234f8633bdc00b477"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w1280/sNoWUZD4S3C4gqWVwvifuiwsJ4m.jpg" size="w1280" width="1280" height="720" id="4ea6860234f8633bdc00b477"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/sNoWUZD4S3C4gqWVwvifuiwsJ4m.jpg" size="original" width="1920" height="1080" id="4ea6860234f8633bdc00b477"/>
</images>
<version>800</version>
<last_modified_at>2013-04-09 03:03:56 UTC</last_modified_at>
</movie>
<movie>
<score/>
<popularity>3</popularity>
<translated>true</translated>
<adult>false</adult>
<language>en</language>
<original_name>Dabangg 2</original_name>
<name>Dabangg 2</name>
<alternative_name>沙曼罕之爆裂警官 2</alternative_name>
<type>movie</type>
<id>147405</id>
<imdb_id>tt2112131</imdb_id>
<url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/147405</url>
<votes>2</votes>
<rating>5.8</rating>
<certification>NR</certification>
<overview>
Dabangg 2 is an upcoming Bollywood action film directed and produced by Arbaaz Khan under the banner of Arbaaz Khan Productions.It is a sequel to the 2010 film Dabangg and is written by Dilip Shukla. Story is set in the city of Kanpur
</overview>
<released>2012-12-21</released>
<images>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w92/5VW8AEfj4r3bu9MtvwvcbWAN53O.jpg" size="thumb" width="92" height="130" id="514727ab760ee3215200fe27"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w154/5VW8AEfj4r3bu9MtvwvcbWAN53O.jpg" size="w154" width="154" height="217" id="514727ab760ee3215200fe27"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/5VW8AEfj4r3bu9MtvwvcbWAN53O.jpg" size="cover" width="185" height="261" id="514727ab760ee3215200fe27"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/5VW8AEfj4r3bu9MtvwvcbWAN53O.jpg" size="w342" width="342" height="483" id="514727ab760ee3215200fe27"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w500/5VW8AEfj4r3bu9MtvwvcbWAN53O.jpg" size="mid" width="500" height="706" id="514727ab760ee3215200fe27"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/5VW8AEfj4r3bu9MtvwvcbWAN53O.jpg" size="original" width="1156" height="1632" id="514727ab760ee3215200fe27"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w300/rWGMdyTydjXXh9YphuU5gQ7wJ8X.jpg" size="thumb" width="300" height="169" id="51472838760ee3216f010a1c"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w780/rWGMdyTydjXXh9YphuU5gQ7wJ8X.jpg" size="poster" width="780" height="439" id="51472838760ee3216f010a1c"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w1280/rWGMdyTydjXXh9YphuU5gQ7wJ8X.jpg" size="w1280" width="1280" height="720" id="51472838760ee3216f010a1c"/>
<image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/rWGMdyTydjXXh9YphuU5gQ7wJ8X.jpg" size="original" width="1920" height="1080" id="51472838760ee3216f010a1c"/>
</images>
<version>2</version>
<last_modified_at>2013-04-28 21:28:49 UTC</last_modified_at>
</movie>
</movies>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

There are two movie Ids in this result. The Id which I want is 147405 but I am only getting the Id 44425. How can I get the other movie ID.

If we see the movie name I searched for `<name>Dabangg 2</name>` bit it send the `<name>Dabangg</name>` also . How can I make a check of name and take that id from the xml.

Comment: When you put example code here on the website, write it in a form that shows the issue. E.g. you don't need to put the database interaction code here if you actually have an issue with the XML parsing. See my exemplary edit.

Comment: I get the following problem with the URL you have provided: *"Warning: `simplexml_load_file(http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/mapi/Dabangg)`: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"*

Comment: @hakre Its beacuse I haven't provided the api with that URL . I dont want to show here publically . But the above URL will fetch the data which I have provided above

Comment: Yes, I'm just seeing this now: *`{"status_code":7,"status_message":"Invalid API key - You must be granted a valid key","location":"http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/mapi/Dabangg"}`*. - You should explicitly say if your code does not work here.

Comment: @hakre Yes, the XML data I have provided you above is the same when you hit with that URL. If you see there are two movies data in it. There were two movies "Dabangg" and "Dabangg 2" . I actually made a search for "Dabangg 2" but in reponse the server gave me both . Now there is only one way left if I can match the DB result name "Dabangg 2" with <name> and fetch the ID for that. how can I achive this ? As per now the ID of "Dabangg" is coming as output :(

Comment: Added you a working answer and also an API key that has been registered to be used in Stackoverflow examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for the exact term like

```
$movieName = 'Dabangg 2';
```

You need to wrap it in double-quotes:

```
$apiKey = '30f44b6ef9472d414e50d2acaa058b60';

$url = sprintf(
    'http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/%s/"%s"',
    $apiKey,
    rawurlencode(trim($movieName))
);
```

Which will allow you to obtain the ID you're looking for immediately:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$movie = $xml->movies->movie;

echo $movieName, ': ', $movie->id; # Dabangg 2: 147405
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` ends execution of current `while`. then do not use it, because after first finding match, it ends the while loop

Comment: I removed still below are the echo Dabangg%202 44425

Comment: @Deonia, move echo inside `while` loop

Comment: I add echo inside loop . it shows Dabangg%202 147405 44425. That means I am getting both Id but how can pick only 147405 which is can be checked on the basis of <name></name> tag

Comment: @Deonia: You need to formulate that decision inside your code. You select from the document what you select from it. I'll review it, but this is likely how it works.

Comment: @hakre Is there is anyway I fetch the ID value on the <name> tag basis